# Looking for methods of showing text or logos on same coloured backgrounds

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, color, text, background

I need to keep the logo/ text the same colour as shown. The problem is that part of the logo is the same colour as the background it's going to be placed on.

I'm running out of ideas to try and show the logo without disrupting the logo itself. I've tried adding drop shadow to it, tried a large chunky white style border but none of it looks quite right. here is an example.

[image: Just so you have an idea of what i'm talking about]

Comment: Did you try a thin white border rather than a chunky one? Or a tight white box?

Comment: It just doesn't look quite right, it's a logo on a website so a simple box won't work, i'll see if I can build a background style box it can sit on I guess.

Comment: Have you tried to reverse the log, for example change color black to white, use transparent background? A good company should have a well prepared logo version for the usage on an colored background ...

Comment: Unfortunately I've got to work with what I'm given, the company's boss refuses to use anything that looks slightly different so I'm stuck with a black and red text logo!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but Kurt's solution seems best to me. Any good logo has alternatives for use on different backgrounds, especially on those of colours present in the logo itself. Up to you, the designer, the daunting task of explaining this to the customer. Try and ask him what he'd want to use as logo in a greyscale publication? This situation is similar.

Comment: If you can't alter the logo.. you need to alter the web site design. Color on color will do more to damage branding than anything else. Any "workaround" is going to appear to be just that.

Comment: You really should have white behind your logo. It can be a box, a 'tag' protruding from the top or side of the page, or make the whole header of the page white while the body remains red.

Comment: You have no decision to make, really. Unless you can change one of two alternatives, the die is cast. Swallow ego and go with customer's directive. They're paying you. Aren't you changing the logo with drop shadows or tinting?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a great deal of information in your question. I assume that the words are normally printed on a white ground and the text is black and red. Your task is to show that logo on a ground which is the "house red" (like the text).

The standard method of a coloured logo is to reverse it out of the background. Doing that retains the logo and the colour.

You could outline the red letters so that they retain their colour. You could use a tint for those letters as shown by sergeydyadyul.

[image: Coloured logos]

Comment: To me the obvious answer is the bottom one - make the red text white to swap its colour with the background.  You still end up with red, black and white.  It's not all that unusual for companies to have different versions of the logo for different background colours, etc.

Comment: Yes: that's what I meant with "the standard method is to reverse it out of the coloured background".

Comment: Thanks for your input Andrew, The problem being I'm not allowed to change the logo/ text itself. Due to my boss knowing nothing about design or websites, he has an attitude of I'm right, therefore I have to go along with what he says, even after explaining a few things. He also refuses to believe other companies have different backgrounds. In the end I changed the colour scheme to allow for the logo to show without problems!

Answer (score 1):

Just some ideas to move you forward

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Don't Explain a thing.**

Do nothing to the logo and submit the job as requested, ASAP. The Boss is not an idiot and when given the job will see the problem and will make appropriate changes. If you only have time for one version, do as you're asked.

If there is enough time, do your suggestion for comparison. Keep it hidden until asked for advice. If no advice is solicited, keep the alternative for your portfolio or the best-selling book about graphic design that you're writing.

**Edit:** What can you do about the *background*?

You might be able to do something about the background without compromising the logo itself. Perhaps the boss is less attached to the background than his "pride & Joy" logo that his favourite niece made for him on his 45th birthday. Here are some starters to generate juice. Ironically, there may be more flexibility there.

- Can you shade the corner where the bug is?
- Can you stick the bug anywhere else in the layout where there is less
  conflict?
- Can you treat the corner where the bug is with some graphic element
  such as the page turned-up revealing the bug?
- Can you isolate the bug inside a border, a splash, a flash, or any
  discontinuity where the bug can be displayed?

Comment: I personally don't think this is a good approach. "Do a bad job because you get paid to do it"? "Hide your logo until you are asked for it"? I would send the original sample along with a white version, so he can see the difference at a glance.

Comment: I didn't say do a bad job. Yes, deliver the job. When asked, show what your idea is. Don't flaunt your design. Let me put it another way. You've designed a logo and someone changes it because it suits them and their friends online encouraged them to ignore what was asked for explicitly and specifically. This person feels that a change is necessary contrary to what they were contracted to do. (As I understand the post.) I may be wrong; but, I'm never in doubt.

Comment: @Yisela The OP admitted that working is this way may compromise the logo design in the eyes of the boss. That puts this into a business decision: violate instructions, compromise existing logo, that's two big invitations for the boss to tell you to take a hike.

Comment: I'd tend to go with something like what Scott mentions in the comments (change the website), or in Andrew's answer (revert the logo, which is a very common practice). If the result looks terrible, not only it can harm your reputation, but it will make you feel quite unhappy, because you are going against your gut. You were hired, as a designer, to use your best professional judgement. But this is just my opinion.

Comment: @Yisela Don't get me wrong. I'm not simply an automaton. I'll defend my designs. But, I'm not out to conquer the world. Some folks want what they want. I have no less talent, and my portfolio is no less attractive because I can take a direct order.

Comment: I agree with you! Until "we want our law firm's font to be comic sans" ;)

Comment: @Stan, when you state that "You've designed a logo and someone changes it because it suits them...", understand: may be you have designed not what they needed in first place. While a logo, made by you, seems to you as a perfect work - to your customer it may seem like "yes, a nice logo, but definitely not what I have asked for".