# Logo on a background of same color

Tags: color, logo, background, composition

I have a logo in white+blue. And I have a background of same blue color. If I simply put a logo over the background - logo's blue part merges with the background. How should I solve such a dilemma? P. S. I am not a designer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a 2-color logo put on a color background of the same hue?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30913/how-to-have-a-2-color-logo-put-on-a-color-background-of-the-same-hue)

Comment: there are [other duplicates](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21175/looking-for-methods-of-showing-text-or-logos-on-same-coloured-backgrounds?rq=1) for the same question

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot? I have a hard time imagining what your problem is. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of different ways you could go about it solving this problem, each with their own pros and cons. The method you choose should reflect your consideration of these in the context of your use case. For example...

**You could add a border around the logo**. This creates a firm separation between the logo and background, but it messes with the integrity of the logo, and could be confused as being part of the logo.

**You could add a drop shadow behind the logo**. This separates the logo and background, more subtly than the border (which may or may not be desired). It also has the effect of adding another layer or plane to your overall image -- the logo is now 'floating above' the background (again, ask yourself if this is desirable or not).

**You could add a containing element between the logo and background**. For instance, a simple white (or what have you) box or [card](https://material.google.com/components/cards.html) can contain the logo and set it apart from the background.

**You could alter the saturation of the background**. Either desaturate it to bring the logo forward, or oversaturate it to achieve the inverse. However, this solution is quickly strolling away from the parameters you specified.

This list is just a starting point, but it gives you an idea of the ways you can achieve what you want, and the consequences to consider in doing so.

Answer (score 5):

My answer would simply be; don't do it.

Create an all white version of the logo or create a white (or any other color than that blue color) container for the logo to sit in. Don't go with borders or shades as they will probably change the appearance of the logo too much.

Answer (score 3):

Usually when logo brand guidelines are established companies create alternate versions of their logos for backgrounds with conflicting colors.

You might consider making an all white (or alternate/monotone color) version of your logo. Doing this to highly detailed logos can get tricky sometimes. If so, try outlines or removing unnecessary superfluous details entirely.

Comment: +1 For the first part. You could add: "Consider hiring a designer to define this case" :o)